# How do you add Read more ... link to posts?

Tags: posts

How do you add Read more ...link to a particular post or to all posts in a blog ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Read more` links usually appear under following conditions:

1. Template uses `the_content()` function for display.
2. Post has `<--more-->` tag in content, which creates `teaser`.

Result is `teaser`, followed by `read more` link.

Sometimes such links are created artificially by appending them to output of `the_excerpt()` function in template.

So to precisely answer your question - it depends on your template tags and how you use `excerpts` and/or `teasers`.

See post (by me) for [writeup on excerpt/teaser differences and mechanics](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-excerpt-teaser/).